# Creating a custom float class by inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, floating-point, precision

I am trying to create a custom float class 'Float' in Python by inheriting the float class and overloading the operators associated with it. I am overloading the arithmetic operators associated with the class so as to obtain the precision of the decimal.Decimal class for arithmetic calculations while maintaining the performance of the float class which is far better than that of the decimal.Decimal class.

This way, I do not need to use the round() function or string formatting whenever I need to display a human readable output.

This is my code with only the addition operator overloaded:

```
class Float(float): #custom float class
    def Float(self,value): #Constructor like method
        self.value = value

    def count_decimal_places(float_num): #Counts decimal places for rounding
        if type(float_num) == int:
            return 0
        return len(str(float_num).split('.')[1])

    def __add__(self, other): #rounds results to the higher number of decimal places
        return round(self.value +other.value, max(self.count_decimal_places(self.value), self.count_decimal_places(other.value))

fo = Float()
fo.Float(3.6)
fo2 = Float()
fo2.Float(5.6)
print(fo + fo2)
```

When I used a constructor directly in the class to assign a value to the 'value' attribute, that did not work.

```
    class Float(float):
            def init(self,value):
                    self.value = value
            def count_decimal_places(float_num):
                    if type(float_num) == int:
                            return 0
                    return len(str(float_num).split('.')[1])
            def __add__(self, other):
                    return round(self.value +other.value, max(self.count_decimal_places(self.value), self.count_decimal_places(other.value))

    fo = Float(3.6)
    fo2 = Float(5.6)
    print(fo + fo2)
```

It generated a syntax error. This is why I used a constructor like method instead in the first code.

Also the **init** method exists for class float in Python and shows up in print(dir(float)) but I am unable to ascertain what it does so I have not used the predefined constructor of class float.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that causes the error. A mistake on the lines above `def __init__` is the most likely cause.

Comment: "I am overloading the arithmetic operators associated with the class so as to obtain the precision of the decimal.Decimal class for arithmetic calculations while maintaining the performance of the float class which is far better than that of the decimal.Decimal class." Why do you believe you can do that? It doesn't seem like you are doing that at all, you are simply rounding (and even then I doubt the performance would be better that `decimal.Decimal`, which is implemented in C, but perhaps... but it is certainly not the same precision, **it's still has the same exact floating point issues**

Comment: I edited my post and added the code from when I used def __init__ as well.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure I understand. I am trying to adjust the number of decimal places for rounding and overload the arithmetic operators so 4.0 - 2.7 stores 1.3 in a variable rather than 1.29999998.

Comment: Also, your `count_decimal_places` method doesn't make sense, you check if the `type` is `int`, but you are always passing it a `float`...

Comment: @AnuragSaksena why do you believe this will be more performant than `decimal.Decimal`? Why do you believe that it will have the same *precision*?

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga I havent added a type check anywhere so I could pass an int data type value as well. But it is true that the function will return the number of decimal places as 1 for input 2.0

Comment: "so 4.0 - 2.7 stores 1.3 in a variable rather than 1.29999998" **no it doesn't do that at all**. I think you are fundamentally mistaken about the nature of floating point errors. `float` objects **cannot store** the value of the decimal number `1.3`, exactly.

Comment: Carcigenicate I fixed the ). Thanks. But it is now generating a new error:Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 10, in __add__
    return round(self.value +other.value, max(self.count_decimal_places(self.value), self.count_decimal_places(other.value)))
AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had mismatching parantheses at the return line of `def __add__(self, other)`. After fixing it I've put the constructor back. You also forgot to put `self` as the first parameter in `count_decimal_places` so I fixed that too. I didn't check the logic of your functions though, but it seems to be working so far:

```
class Float(float): #custom float class
    def __init__(self,value): #Constructor like method
        self.value = value

    def count_decimal_places(self, float_num): #Counts decimal places for rounding
        if type(float_num) == int:
            return 0
        return len(str(float_num).split('.')[1])

    def __add__(self, other): #rounds results to the higher number of decimal places
        return round(self.value +other.value, max(self.count_decimal_places(self.value), self.count_decimal_places(other.value)))

fo = Float(3)
fo2 = Float(5.6)
print(fo+fo2)
```

> Output: 8.6